# My whole system crashed today without any warning

Tags: 17.10, crash

Please I need help urgently. I don't know what to do and I need someone to guide me how to restore back my system.  Ubuntu 17.10 would not boot today and the Dell machine kept checking the hardware and found nothing.  I am trying to restore the system from my usb flash stick.  I still didn't manage to boot till now... Can someone pls help and guide me step by step I'm still a new user please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep all your files, you can try running an install from disk/usb, go to "Try Ubuntu without installing". Access all the files in your drive and back them up in a cloud or separate drive and then reinstall if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I didn't see this option when I ran the restore tool, the only option worthy of trying was (install ubuntu 16.10 along with ubuntu 17.4 to keep all your files), so I tried it.  The first attempt failed.  I tried again and it seems like it worked.  After it finished, it asked me to reboot and now it's been rebooting for like 15 minutes, is this normal?

Comment: I'm not sure what restore tool you're talking about, but I would just create a bootable usb/disc and run system from that device. In the grub menu, you'll be given an option to choose whether to try ubuntu or install it. Go to try ubuntu and that'll run the os from the boot media.

Comment: I don't have a grub menu.  The system can't see any OS

Comment: I'm using my Windows machine now, can you tell me how to create a bootable usb/disc, from where?

Comment: So download the OS .iso file from here: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop. After download rufus from here: https://rufus.akeo.ie/. Then use Rufus to create a bootable stick. There will be an icon next to "create a bootable stick" and then select the .iso file. After, boot the system from the usb, and follow the instructions I gave earlier. Let me know what happens, and if it doesn't work, try to be as detailed as you can and I can help the best I can.

Comment: I was using ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Scroll down a little farther on the link and it'll have the 17.10.1 download

Comment: Update: the ubuntu machine is still showing the "Ubuntu" logo at the start of the booting attempt but nothing is happening for the past 15 minutes.  Should I force shutdown the system or what?

Comment: Yeah, I would if you just want the files from that system. Those files will still be in the hard drive. After you get the files, perform a fresh install and it'll run just fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72794/discussion-between-nermeen-hussein-and-lumbeezl).